# Make white transparent in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have some complex code that creates a tikz picture, called image A. The background areas of this picture are white, as are some foreground areas, which are painted with a white fill. I now want to lay this picture on top of image B, such that all white parts of image A are rendered transparent.

It would be ideal if image A could be created so that the white areas were simply not painted, but this is not possible, because many of the white areas are curve paths---so it's easy to draw them directly, but hard to draw their complement.

Can this be done? At the moment I'm having to render images A and B separately, take screenshots, and do this layering in GIMP.

An example (added by another user):

First draw a shape using white to 'erase' parts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[fill=cyan] (0,0) circle (1);
    \path[draw=white, line width=10pt] (-0.1,-1.2) to[out=70, in=-70] (-0.1,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now try drawing something behind it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[draw=orange, line width=5pt] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \path[fill=cyan] (0,0) circle (1);
    \path[draw=white, line width=10pt] (-0.1,-1.2) to[out=70, in=-70] (-0.1,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The goal is to have the orange line go behind the blue areas but show through the white part, so you can see a segment of the orange line in between the two blue regions.

Comment: Yes, I think so. But I need an example to play with. You probably need to do it all in one picture, but presumably that shouldn't be a problem. At least, the way I'm thinking might work probably needs that. But, like I say, hard to know without something to fiddle with.

Comment: `tikzfadingfrompicture` or `transparency group`. Cannot tell for sure. Perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323315/51022 helps

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added an example. I could ask my own question if you prefer, but apart from the example it would be exactly the same as your question.

Comment: @N.Virgo The linked solution by Symbol 1 ist in my opinion easier to achieve but not every viewer renders it the same way, so it might not be as portable as the more complex `spath3` solution (which is also not exactly the same but close enough for this example).

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to achieve using `spath3` and `intersections` Ti*k*Z libraries.

You need to create the paths (but not draw them), save them and then intersect the circle with the two arcs and get the components. `spath3` allow all these operations.

For example, something like this:

```
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,spath3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
% orignal paths:
\path[draw=orange,line width=5pt] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\path[spath/save=A] (0,0) circle (1);
\path[spath/save=B,xshift=-5pt] (-0.1,-1.2) to[out=70, in=-70] (-0.1,1.2);
\path[spath/save=C,xshift= 5pt] (-0.1,-1.2) to[out=70, in=-70] (-0.1,1.2);
% spath3 operatios:
\tikzset
{
  spath/split at intersections={A}{B},
  spath/split at intersections={A}{C},
  spath/get components of={A}\Acpts,
  spath/get components of={B}\Bcpts,
  spath/get components of={C}\Ccpts,
}
% new paths
\fill[cyan,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{2},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Bcpts{2},weld},
     ];
\fill[cyan,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{4},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Ccpts{2},reverse,weld},
     ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way to do this while keeping the images in a vector format. However, as you are already using GIMP, and thus converting to bitmap, I assume you don't mind that too much. If so, the process can be automated using some command line tools. Here is a bash script that does this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# input files expected in pdf, output in png
bg_pdf=$1
fg_pdf=$2
output_png=$3

# generate png file names
bg_png=${bg_pdf%.pdf}.png
fg_png=${fg_pdf%.pdf}.png

# first, convert both pdf files to png. The best tool for this
# is pdftoppm from popplerutils. We switch off antialasing
# of fonts (-aa no) and other elements (--aaVector no) in
# order to avoid ghosting at the edges. The -r option sets the
# resolution (pixels in the output image per inch of input image).
# Use a high enough resolution, you can always reduce image size 
# (and maybe apply antialising) later. 

pdftoppm -r 300 -png -aa no -aaVector no $bg_pdf > $bg_png
pdftoppm -r 300 -png -aa no -aaVector no $fg_pdf > $fg_png

# now, we use imagemagick's convert to convert white to transparency in the
# foreground image

convert $fg_png -transparent white $fg_png

# finally, we use imagemagick's composite to stack them on top of each other.
# the -gravity center option centers the images to each other; it is not
# needed if they are of equal size.

composite -gravity center $fg_png $bg_png $output_png

# you could also use convert to reduce size and apply antialias
# convert $output_png -antialias -resize 50% halfsize.png
```

Save this as `script.sh` and make executable (`chmod +x script.sh`). Call this like

```sh
./script.sh background.pdf foreground.pdf composite.png
```

A breathtakingly beautiful example (input files uploaded as PNG, but I tested at home on the PDF originals):

Background
[image: background]

Foreground
[image: foreground]

Composite
[image]

Comment: I don't doubt that it is a good answer, but I see no TeX-LaTeX code in it...