# Is there a way to draw/fill with eraser (tikz)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish build up a `tikz` picture from layers. Is there a way to draw/fill one of the layer with "eraser" (not transparency)? Somehow:

[image]

I have no idea therefore neither MWE :-/

(I know, that there is an easier way to do the example document above, but that is only an example.)

Comment: mwe is usually added to save us from the annoyance of writing those rectangle and color parts.

Comment: your question is not clear. see, if the following MWE gives what you expect: `\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style args = {#1/#2}{minimum size=#1, fill=#2, font=\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
                        ]
\node[box=44mm/green,draw]  {Text};
\node[box=33mm/red]         {};
\node[box=22mm/white,draw]  {};
\node[box=11mm/blue]        {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: What you are asking cannot be constructed by piling layers on top of each other; in effect, you want your eraser layer to cut into the layers beneath it. AFAIK that is impossible. This question discusses a possible work-around: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336502/make-white-transparent-in-a-tikz-picture/336509#336509

Comment: Keyword: **knockout group** and **inverse clipping**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of erasing, you could simply not draw the filling in the first place:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[red, line width=3pt] (0.2,0.2) rectangle (0.8,0.8);
\fill[blue] (0.4,0.4) rectangle (0.6,0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]