# Crossing discontinuity with complex background

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, backgrounds, transparency

I'm using the technique [from this TeX.SO answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522228/2113) to produce a circuit with a crossing (I'm using Beamer because in the next step I'll use that to set a background image)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newlength{\crossing}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\crossing}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/crossing/size}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,transform shape]
    \draw[name path=p1] (0,0) circle -- (2,0) circle;
    \draw[name path=p2] (1,1) circle -- (1,-1) circle;

    \path [name intersections={of=p1 and p2,by=cross}]
          [fill=white] (cross) circle[radius=0.5\crossing];
    \path (cross) node[jump crossing,rotate=-90]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This works as long as the background is white. However, if the background is not white, but some arbitrary image, it becomes apparent that the crossing-over discontinuity was achieved not by erasure, but by filling with white:

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz\node[opacity=0.1] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};}
```

[image]

So I thought I should apply [this technique](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323315/2113) and put everything in a knockout group:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,transform shape]
  \begin{scope}[transparency group=knockout]
    \draw[name path=p1] (0,0) circle -- (2,0) circle;
    \draw[name path=p2] (1,1) circle -- (1,-1) circle;

    \path [name intersections={of=p1 and p2,by=cross}]
          [fill,opacity=0] (cross) circle[radius=0.5\crossing];
    \path (cross) node[jump crossing,rotate=-90]{};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But now the circle that's supposed to clear the intersection doesn't seem to do anything:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, how do I achieve my desired result?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel but that means I have to split the drawing of the `(1,1) -- (1,-1)` edge into two commands, which are apart from each other by the drawing of the crossing... that is going to decrease maintainability.

Comment: Have you tried another PDF viewer? As the linked answer says, this is viewer dependent. The linked answer doesn't work for me, either.

Comment: If you look at the code of the `jump crossing`, in [`pgfcircshapes.tex`, around line 618](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/blob/a1f3e3b63492f92280e69ac00efcb4df9c1889c9/tex/pgfcircshapes.tex#L606-L625), you can see that the broken "node" is obtained by just drawing two segments. FWIK, there is no way to "unpath" a path once is drawn; @Qrrbrbirlbel comment is the way to. Maybe you can embed the thing in a macro.

Comment: Another question: what is the idea with `\draw (0,0) circle -- (2,0) circle;`? What are the `circle`s doing there?

Comment: @rmano oh that's just there I guess because my original code had some shapes at the path endpoints and I didn't remove them correctly when minimizing...

Comment: @Rmano "unpathing" is probably exactly what I'd like -- a retroactive clipping of a disk around the intersection...

Comment: You can find the point by using `path`s instead of `draw`s, do an inverse clip in a `scope` (somewhere you should have code for that around here ;-) ), re-draw the lines, exit the scope, and add the `jump crossing`. But I still think @Qrrbrbirlbel suggestion is sounder.

Comment: To reiterate: Using another viewer your final picture works as intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the circuit before the colored background picture in a `transparency group` and add the option `blend mode=multiply`. This, however, will only look nice if the drawing in the front is purely black:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz\node[opacity=0.1] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};}
    
\newlength{\crossing}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\crossing}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/crossing/size}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, transform shape]
    \begin{scope}[transparency group, blend mode=multiply]
        \draw[name path=p1] (0,0) -- (2,0);
        \draw[name path=p2] (1,1)-- (1,-1);

        \path [name intersections={of=p1 and p2, by=cross}]
              [fill=white] (cross) circle[radius=0.5\crossing];
        \path (cross) node[jump crossing, rotate=-90]{};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm accepting this one for now as this is the least disruptive to the structure of the actual figure.

Answer (score 6):

Yet an other solution. -you can make everything that is white transparent by using `tikzfadingfrompicture` like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, backgrounds, intersections}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newlength{\crossing}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\crossing}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/crossing/size}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading, background rectangle/.style={fill=transparent!0}, show background rectangle, scale=4, transform shape]
\draw[name path=p1] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[name path=p2] (1,1) -- (1,-1);
\path [name intersections={of=p1 and p2, by=cross}]
[fill=white] (cross) circle[radius=0.5\crossing];
\path (cross) node[jump crossing, rotate=-90]{};
\coordinate (sw) at (current bounding box.south west);
\coordinate (ne) at (current bounding box.north east);
\path (0,0) circle[radius=10]; %encompassing circle for alignment
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myinvfading]
\fill[transparent!0] (0,0) (sw) rectangle (ne);
\fill[path fading=myfading, fit fading=false, transparent!100] (sw) rectangle (ne);
\path (0,0) circle[radius=10]; %encompassing circle for alignment
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[opacity=0.2] at (4,0) {\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}};
\fill[path fading=myinvfading, fit fading=false]  (sw) rectangle (ne);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lines with a crossing symbol on top of a picture]

**Edit:**

The solution uses two colors `transparent!0`(white) and `transparent!100`(black).

- In `myfading` the background is `transparent!0` (or white for the filled node) and everything is drawn normally on this background.
- In `myinvfading` the background is `transparent!0` and `myfading` is
  inserted with the color `transparent!100`. This inverts the colors,
  and we are now back to the original colors.
- Now `myinvfading` can be draw black in the `tikzpicture` as the final result.

Comment: "you can make everything that is white transparent" This would be a terrific solution to my problem! Unfortunately, the code you show seems to be much more complicated than that -- the intro makes it sound like I can just put something on my `tikzpicture` to handle white as transparent, but then you seem to be drawing in multiple passes... can you expand your answer with explaining what's going on there?

Comment: "much more complicated than that" - Much more complicated than what? The solution is not simple. I would not use it - it is a hack that kind of patches an other hack (filling an area with white to cover some unwanted lines and hope these lines align with the cover nodes lines). I will add some explaning text.

Comment: I meant it's much more complicated than just telling TikZ to regard all white as transparent :)

Answer (score 3):

I find it a bit on the convoluted side, but... you can find the point by using paths instead of draws, do an inverse clip in a scope ([adapted from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59168/38080)), re-draw the lines, exit the scope, and add the jump crossing:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz\node[opacity=0.1] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newlength{\crossing}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\crossing}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/crossing/size}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
    clip even odd rule/.code={\pgfseteorule}, % Credit to Andrew Stacey 
    invclip/.style={
        clip,insert path=
            [clip even odd rule]{
                [reset cm](-\maxdimen,-\maxdimen)rectangle(\maxdimen,\maxdimen)
            }
    }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,transform shape]
    \path[name path=p1] (0,0)  -- (2,0) ;
    \path[name path=p2] (1,1) -- (1,-1) ;
    \begin{scope}[overlay]
        \path [name intersections={of=p1 and p2,by=cross}];
        \clip [invclip]
            (cross) circle[radius=0.5\crossing];
        \draw (0,0)  -- (2,0) ;
        \draw (1,1) -- (1,-1) ;
    \end{scope}
    \path (cross) node[jump crossing,rotate=-90]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(`okular` is struggling with the antialiasing here a bit...)

Comment: Notice the correction due to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290508/38080, but well, you got the idea

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel, adjusted

Comment: This can be improved a bit by `save path`-ing `p1` and `p2` and then `\draw`-ing them with `use path`, to avoid specifying the same path details twice.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments and the linked answer, the `knockout` method is viewer dependent.

Below, I've implemented a `crossings over=<a>--<b> over {<c1>--<d1>, …, <cn>--<dn>}` that will draw a line from `<a>` to `<b>` crossing all given lines. The order is important!

The values `crossing over radius` and `crossing over clearance` change the outcome of that little arc.

The key `crossing over style` with either paramater `multiply` or `knockout` must be used at an encompassing scope.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
  \tikz\node[inner sep=+0pt,opacity=0.1]
    {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};}
\tikzset{
  crossing over radius/.initial=.4mm,
  crossing over clearance/.initial=3*\the\pgflinewidth,
  @@crossings over/.style n args={3}{
    @@@crossings over/.style args={##1--##2}{
      @crossing over={#1}{#2}{##1}{##2}},
    @@@crossings over/.list={#3}},
  crossings over/.style args={#1--#2 over #3}{
    insert path={
      coordinate (@after@intersect@) at (#1)
      let \p{@diff@}=($(#1)-(#2)$),
          \n{@diff@}={atan2(\y{@diff@},\x{@diff@})} in
      (#1)[@@crossings over={#1}{#2}{#3}] -- (#2)}},
  @crossing over/.style n args={4}{
    insert path={
      -- ($(intersection of #1--#2 and #3--#4)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/crossing over radius}!(#1)$)
      coordinate (@before@intersect@)
      \pgfextra\pgfinterruptpath
        \draw[@crossing over style, line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/crossing over clearance}]
          (@before@intersect@)
            arc[start angle=\n{@diff@}, delta angle=-180, radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/crossing over radius}];
      \endpgfinterruptpath\endpgfextra
      arc[start angle=\n{@diff@}, delta angle=-180, radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/crossing over radius}]}},
  crossing over style/.is choice,
  @crossing over style/.code=%
    \tikzerror{You need to use "crossing over style" with option "multiply" or "knockout"},
  crossing over style/multiply/.style={
    @crossing over style/.style={draw=white},
    transparency group, blend mode=multiply},
  crossing over style/knockout/.style={
    @crossing over style/.style={draw=white,opacity=0},
    transparency group=knockout}}
\newcommand*\myPicture[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, transform shape, #1]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0) coordinate (B) at (2,0)
     coordinate (C) at (1,1) coordinate (D) at (1,-1)
     coordinate (E) at (0,1) coordinate (F) at (2, -.4)
     coordinate (G) at (1.5,.5) coordinate (H) at (-.5,1);
    \draw (A) -- (B);
    \draw [crossings over=C--D over A--B];
    \draw[green] [crossings over=E--F over {C--D, A--B}];
    \draw[red] [crossings over=G--H over {C--D, E--F}];
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

% \begin{frame}
% \myPicture{}% error
% \end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\myPicture{crossing over style=multiply}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\myPicture{crossing over style=knockout}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

Notice the different greens and reds.

#### multiply blend

[image]

#### knockout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since my other answer is based on a very different approach, I will add this other solution that is based on the mechanics and tools provided by CircuiTi*k*Z.

First of all, things are much easier if you use the `jump crossing` node provided by CircuiTi*k*Z:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz\node[opacity=0.1] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=4, transform shape]
    \node at (1,0)[jump crossing, rotate=-90] (X) {};
    \draw (0,0) -- (X.south) (X.north) -- (2,0);
    \draw (1,1) -- (X.west) (X.east) -- (1,-1);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But if you still want a solution based on bipoles (using `to`-paths as suggested in the CircuiTi*k*Z manual), you can imitate this by defining a new custom bipole called `crossing under` which essentially draws a line with a small gap, exactly where the arc of the `crossing` bipole would sit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz\node[opacity=0.1] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};}

\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole
{}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/crossing/size}}
{crossing under}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/crossing/size}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/crossing/size}}{
    \pgfscope
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.4\pgf@circ@res@right-.4pt}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.4\pgf@circ@res@right+.4pt}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
}
\pgfcirc@activate@bipole@simple{l}{crossing under}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=4, transform shape]
    \draw (0,0) to[crossing under] (2,0);
    \draw (1,1) to[crossing] (1,-1);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]