# Tikz equivalent for pst-rputover

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

For pstricks the package [pst-rputover](https://ctan.org/pkg/rputover) (new on ctan since 2017-03-28) has been created to solve following problem

> In brief, I'm looking for a version of \rput* that blocks out lines but not fill colors.

raised here:
[Is there a variant of \rput* in PSTricks that preserves background fill colors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353748/is-there-a-variant-of-rput-in-pstricks-that-preserves-background-fill-colors)

I am interested in a solution for tikz. I have recreated the minimal example with tikz:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[blue!40] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \fill[red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,2)(1,1)(2,2)} -- cycle;
  \draw(1,0)--(1,2);
  \node at (1,1) {\Large\sf label};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The expected output should be

[image]

I am evaluating following options in tikz:

- draw/fill/text opacity
- transparency groups
- `\begin{scope}`
- `\begin{pgfonlayer}`

Note the `knockout` feature is not supported by all PDF Viewer. I can confirm that it does not work in Skim and Preview on macOS.

However, I have not figured out yet how to solve this.

**UPDATE**
I want to add parts of the picture I am working on to clarify that lines might cross several nodes which is a priori not clear:

[image]
[image]

**pst-rputover doc details**

> The style combines two ideas. The **first idea**, suggested by the StackExchange user Werner on this page, is to use `\psDefBoxNodes` in pst-node.sty to get the coordinates of the corners of the box occupied by each label. The **second idea** is to use these coordinates and `\psclip` to remove the parts of the objects in the argument of `\coverable` that overlap with the labels. The only subtlety in implementing this second idea is that we want to do a ‘reverse clip’: we want to keep the areas outside the labels, not the ones inside.

Related questions

- [Relative transparency in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263890)
- [TikZ: Node fill which is opaque to entities in tikzpicture but transparent to background color/image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321974)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for completeness: this is a version which also takes into account rounded corners or, more generally, arbitrary node shapes. And it spares you from typing a lot of coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995/121799
\tikzset{
  use path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}}
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{remember path/.style={save path=\tmprotect}}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/121799
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={(current bounding box.north
        east) rectangle (current bounding box.south west)}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[blue!40] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \fill[red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,2)(1,1)(2,2)} -- cycle;
  \node[remember path,font=\Large\sf] at (1,1) {label};
  \clip[use path=\tmprotect,reverseclip];
  \draw(1,0)--(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[blue!40] (-1,0) rectangle (3,4);
  \fill[red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(-1,4)(0,2)(1,1)(2,2)(3,4)} -- cycle;
  \node[remember path,font=\Large\sf,rounded corners] at (1,1) {label};
  \clip[use path=\tmprotect,reverseclip];
  \node[remember path,font=\Large\sf,shape=diamond] at (2,2) {label 3};
  \clip[use path=\tmprotect,reverseclip];
  \node[remember path,font=\Large\sf,shape=ellipse] at (0,2) {label 2};
  \clip[use path=\tmprotect,reverseclip];
  \fill[gray,opacity=0.2] (-1,0) rectangle (3,4);
  \draw [blue,thick] (-1,4) -- (1,0) -- (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Great! Is \tmprotect already predefined?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner No, only [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448925/121799).

Answer (score 6):

You can clip against the labels:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \fill[color=blue!40] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \fill[red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,2)(1,1)(2,2)} -- cycle;

  \node at (1,1) (mynodeA){\Large\sffamily label};
  \node at (0.5,1.5) (mynodeB){\sffamily label};

  \begin{scope}
  \foreach \n in {mynodeA, mynodeB}{
    \path [clip] 
          (\n.north east) -- 
          (\n.south east) --
          (\n.south west) -- 
          (\n.north west) -- cycle
          (current bounding box.south east) --
          (current bounding box.north east) --
          (current bounding box.north west) --
          (current bounding box.south west) -- cycle;
  }

  \draw(1,0)--(1,2);
  \draw(0.5,0)--(0.5,2);
  \draw(0,1.8)--(2,0.5);
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks like what I want.  The actual picture contains 55 nodes and 120 edges which have to be clipped. I think I will use a foreach loop to to define the clippath for every node to make the code more manageable.

Comment: Your rputover code is actually doing something similar.

Answer (score 2):

with drawing line in two parts?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[blue!40] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \fill[red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,2)(1,1)(2,2)} -- cycle;
  \node at (1,1)  (label) {\Large\sf label};
  \draw (1,0) -- (label) (label) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that is how I created the expected output. The actual document is complicated and doing this manually is not feasible. I really look for an `\rputover` equivalent.

Comment: margin=3.14 - - > :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, just for fun ... (my country is so tiny that you will miss it if we haven't have so accurate defined borders ;-) )

Comment: @Zarko I will read your answers even more carefully in the future. :)